# How can I run the same command on all Ganeti nodes?

Tags: remote-access, ganeti

When administering a Ganeti cluster, it is important to maintain one of the main assumptions Ganeti does: all nodes (at least inside the same group) are equal.

How can I run the same command on the entire cluster?

*Full disclosure: I am being paid to work on Ganeti.*

Answer (score 2):

Ganeti by default replicates on all nodes the list of all nodes in this file:

```
/var/lib/ganeti/ssconf_node_list
```

Being a newline-separated list of fully qualified domain names, you can pass it directly to [`dsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dsh.1.html):

```
dsh -M -f /var/lib/ganeti/ssconf_node_list \
  "apt-get install update && apt-get install upgrade"
```

Otherwise, [`gnt-cluster command`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/gnt-cluster.8.html) also works:

```
gnt-cluster command \
  "apt-get install update && apt-get install upgrade"
```